# Modifying the results of my query to filter by a date range

Tags: powershell

I have this code working when I use it without the date range filter however when I add it I get no results when doing a general search without a date filter and also no results when I put in a date as well. But the code work fine without the filter code added. Ultimately the results I want is to find all records if I don't specify a date range and then to only find the results in the date range if I do specify a date range. I think the issue I am also having is my database fields for DateTime are formatted like this 7/5/2023  6:44:52 which includes the time but I only want to filter by the date portion of that field ( still showing the time but only in the results )

this is the code I have

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Create the form
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Customer Check Payments"
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(820, 525)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.FormBorderStyle = [Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog # Set the form to a fixed size
$form.MaximizeBox = $false # Disable maximize button
$form.MinimizeBox = $false # Disable minimize button

# Create label and text box for CustNum
$labelCustNum = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
$labelCustNum.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 20)
$labelCustNum.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$labelCustNum.Text = "Enter Customer Number:"
$form.Controls.Add($labelCustNum)

$textBoxCustNum = New-Object Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBoxCustNum.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 50)
$textBoxCustNum.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxCustNum)

# Create a button to execute the query
$buttonExecute = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonExecute.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 90)
$buttonExecute.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$buttonExecute.Text = "Find Payments"
$form.Controls.Add($buttonExecute)

# Create a button to print the results
$buttonPrint = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonPrint.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(120, 90)
$buttonPrint.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$buttonPrint.Text = "Print Results"
$buttonPrint.Add_Click({
    $printDialog = New-Object Windows.Forms.PrintDialog
    $printDialog.UseEXDialog = $true

    if ($printDialog.ShowDialog() -eq [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $printDocument = New-Object Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
        $printDocument.DocumentName = "Customer Check Payments"
        $printDocument.Add_PrintPage({
            param($sender, $e)
            $e.Graphics.DrawString("Customer Check Payments", (New-Object Drawing.Font "Arial", 16), [Drawing.Brushes]::Black, 100, 100)

            $rowIndex = 0
            foreach ($row in $dataGridView.Rows) {
                $text = ""
                $columnIndex = 0
                foreach ($cell in $row.Cells) {
                    $text += $cell.Value.ToString()
                    if ($columnIndex -lt $row.Cells.Count - 1) {
                        $text += "  "
                    }
                    $columnIndex++
                }
                $e.Graphics.DrawString($text, (New-Object Drawing.Font "Arial", 12), [Drawing.Brushes]::Black, 100, 150 + $rowIndex * 20)
                $rowIndex++
            }
        })

        $printDocument.Print()
    }
})
$form.Controls.Add($buttonPrint)

# Create a button to close the script
$buttonCloseScript = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonCloseScript.Text = "Close Program"
$buttonCloseScript.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(230, 90)
$buttonCloseScript.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$buttonCloseScript.Add_Click({
    # Close both the admin form and the main form
    $form.Close()
})

$form.Controls.Add($buttonCloseScript)  # Add the Close Script button

# Create DataGridView to display the results
$dataGridView = New-Object Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 140)
$dataGridView.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(780, 320)
$dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = [Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode]::Fill
$dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = $false # Disable adding new rows
$dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = $false  # Hide row header
$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)

# Create date pickers
$startDatePicker = New-Object Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$startDatePicker.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(325, 50)
$form.Controls.Add($startDatePicker)

$endDatePicker = New-Object Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$endDatePicker.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(535, 50)
$form.Controls.Add($endDatePicker)

# Create Filter button
$buttonFilter = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonFilter.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(400, 90)
$buttonFilter.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$buttonFilter.Text = "Filter"
$buttonFilter.Add_Click({
    ExecuteQuery
})
$form.Controls.Add($buttonFilter)

# Function to execute the SQL query and populate the DataGridView
function ExecuteQuery {
    $server = ".\PCAMERICA"
    $database = "lyleoil"
    $user = "sa"
    $password = "pcAmer1ca"

    $startDate = $startDatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    $endDate = $endDatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    $query = @"
        SELECT CustNum,
               ABS(Trans_Amount) AS Payment,
               Payment_Info AS Check_Number,
               FORMAT(DateTime, 'MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt') AS Payment_Date
        FROM AR_Transactions
        WHERE CustNum = '$($textBoxCustNum.Text)'
          AND Payment_Method = 'CH'
          AND DateTime >= '$startDate'
          AND DateTime <= '$endDate'
        ORDER BY DateTime DESC;
"@

    # Create a connection to the SQL server
    $connectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;User Id=$user;Password=$password;"
    $connection = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
    $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = $query

    try {
        # Open the connection
        $connection.Open()

        # Execute the SQL query and get the result
        $adapter = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
        $dataset = New-Object Data.DataSet
        $adapter.Fill($dataset) | Out-Null

        # Close the connection
        $connection.Close()

        # Display the result in the DataGridView
        $dataGridView.DataSource = $dataset.Tables[0]
    }
    catch {
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($_.Exception.Message, "Error", "Ok", "Error")
    }
}

# Wire up the button click event to execute the query
$buttonExecute.Add_Click({
    ExecuteQuery
})

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog()
`
```

the results I am looking for is to show all results if no date range is specified and then to filter those results if a date range is specified

`

Comment: Could you try to change your code to a [MRE] please?

Comment: not sure how to do that ?

Comment: What data type is the ```DateTime``` column in the database? Can you also give an example value from a record and a start / end filter that you expect to return that record but doesn’t?

Comment: not sure on the data type but when searching for a customer number the goal it to show all records if no date is specified to filter and if a date is specified then to just show the result for that date range say August 4 2023 to August 6 2023 ? I hope that better explains what I am trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering comes from the fact that when no date range is specified, the script is still including the date conditions in the SQL query. This will filter out all the records which don't fall within the default date range provided by the DateTimePicker controls.

To fix this, you can modify the `ExecuteQuery` function to only apply the date filter if specific conditions are met.

```
function ExecuteQuery {
    $server = ".\PCAMERICA"
    $database = "lyleoil"
    $user = "sa"
    $password = "pcAmer1ca"

    $startDate = $startDatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    $endDate = $endDatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    $dateFilter = ""
    if ($startDate -ne $null -and $endDate -ne $null) {
        $dateFilter = "AND CAST(DateTime AS DATE) >= '$startDate' AND CAST(DateTime AS DATE) <= '$endDate'"
    }

    $query = @"
        SELECT CustNum,
               ABS(Trans_Amount) AS Payment,
               Payment_Info AS Check_Number,
               FORMAT(DateTime, 'MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt') AS Payment_Date
        FROM AR_Transactions
        WHERE CustNum = '$($textBoxCustNum.Text)'
          AND Payment_Method = 'CH'
          $dateFilter
        ORDER BY DateTime DESC;
"@

    # ... (rest of your function)
}
```

The changes made:

1. Created a `$dateFilter` variable to hold the date filter portion of the query.
2. Used the `CAST` function in SQL to only compare the date portion of the DateTime field.
3. Modified the SQL query to use the `$dateFilter` value conditionally.

Now, the function should return all results when no date range is specified and filter the results based on the specified date range when provided.

Comment: unfortunately Adam I tried adding that and still got no results for the search without the date filter ... the query returns an empty results table ? I appreciate your assistance but not sure if something is missing or overlooked ... thank you for your help